# Golang: Simultaneous function Calls for http post request

Tags: http, go, concurrency, simultaneous

I need to call multiple URL at the same time. My functions get called at the same time (in milli seconds)  but the moment I add a Http post request to the code it gets called one after the other. Below is the code:

```
Check(url1)
Check(url2)

func Check(xurl string) {

    nowstartx    := time.Now()
    startnanos   := nowstartx.UnixNano()
    nowstart := startnanos / 1000000
    fmt.Println(nowstart)

    json = {"name" : "test"}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", xurl, bytes.NewBuffer(json))
    req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "myvalue")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)

    } else {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        body, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    }

}
```

Appreciate help, I need to get the same time (in milliseconds) when I run the program.

Comment: They were never at the same time, you're call each serially, they were just executed very quickly. Have you gone over any of the documentation on Go concurrency? For example: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1

Comment: I went through this https://www.goinggo.net/2014/01/concurrency-goroutines-and-gomaxprocs.html  and it should call concurrently. I tried multple times and it actually did call concurrently except when i added the post request. Is there a way to call multiple http post requests concurrently?

Comment: No where in there are you starting a new goroutine, so you're not adding any concurrency and those 2 calls could not be concurrently executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is achieved by using [Goroutines](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines)

```
go Check(url1)
go Check(url2)

func Check(xurl string) {

    nowstartx    := time.Now()
    startnanos   := nowstartx.UnixNano()
    nowstart := startnanos / 1000000
    fmt.Println(nowstart)

    json = {"name" : "test"}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", xurl, bytes.NewBuffer(json))
    req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "myvalue")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)

    } else {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        body, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    }

}
```